# How to represent value which have same field name in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

How to represent two columns which have the same name in Django? I have designed views and template below. However, the second and third column didn't show.

Here is the my raw query

```
cursor = connection.cursor()

query = str("SELECT\n"
            " MG.valData,\n"
            " MG0.valData as value1,\n"
            " MG1.valData as value2,\n"

            " FROM\n"
            " T_USER AS TU\n"

            " LEFT JOIN M_GENERAL AS MG\n"
            " ON MG.Cd='002'\n"

            " LEFT JOIN M_GENERAL AS MG0\n"
            " ON MG0.Cd='001'\n"

             " LEFT JOIN M_GENERAL AS MG1\n"
            " ON MG1.Cd='001'\n")

cursor.execute(query)
row = dictfetchall(cursor,)
return row
```

Here is template

```
{% for item in table_data %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ item.MG.valData|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.MG0.valData|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.MG1.valData|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I also tried used the alias like `item.value1` and `item.value2` in template. But it still showed blank values. Does anyone know the mistakes?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not saying to change anything, but you aren't really using the Django ORM that well.  Is there a reason that you aren't using models.py and standard ways of accessing your db?

Comment: thank you for your respond @sahutchi i use raw query to get more complex values from many tables. The query above just a simple prototype which show my specific problem (could not show the same field name or alias field name).

Comment: That makes since then @natadecoco.  I won't be able to help out, as I normally avoid operating outside the ORM but get there may be times where that is required.  How I'd troubleshoot is the print the row to the terminal just to see exactly what's getting spit out from the query.  Wish I could be more help.

Comment: I'm skeptical of your assumption that the ORM will not do what you want it to do. Django has a powerful ORM and it's very very rare that I run against a constraint. Even if you need to perform raw SQL queries, you should not do it in the way that you are.

I suggest you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/ - it is likely that - in changing your implementation - it will fix your issue.